# Evenly space images in div using percentages

Tags: html, css, hybrid-mobile-app

I need to space four images aligned horizontally evenly in a row. I am aware that this has been asked many times here, yet none of the solutions I found have worked for me. They all seem to rely on either a fixed width for the row, or a fixed width for the images. I need to specify both in percentages.

My Html:

```
<div id="tabBar">

                <div id="PDiv">
                    <img id="Person" src="images/icons/tabBar/image0.png">
                </div>
                <div id="SDiv">
                    <img id="Sale" src="images/icons/tabBar/image1.png">
                </div>
                <div id="CtDiv">
                    <img id="Current" src="images/icons/tabBar/image2.png">
                </div>
                <div id="FDiv">
                    <img id="Food" src="images/icons/tabBar/image3.png">
                </div>
                <span id="Stretch"></span>
            </div>
```

The CSS

```
#tabBar
{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #F3F3F3;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: justify;

}
#PDiv, #SDiv, #CDiv, #FDiv
{
    background-color: #F3F3F3;
    width: 24%;
    vertical-align: top;
    height: auto;
    display: inline-block;
}
#Stretch
{
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
}
```

The issue with this method is that I am building a mobile hybrid app. Therefore, it will have to work on many screen sizes. Currently it looks great on larger screens and computers, but on phones with smaller-sized screens, either the images begin to get cut off, or one of them goes and makes a new line. Instead, I need the images to just scale down and stay evenly spaced.

Comment: Can we assume all your images have the same dimensions?

Comment: Yes, they are all the same dimensions to the pixel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried scaling your images with CSS, like so:

```
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

This will prevent you images of creating new lines, or being cut off.

EDIT:

jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/ATube/

Comment: Thanks, that helped significantly, however now the smaller the page width the further up the tab bar the images position themselves. I would just use a margin or padding, but the amount they position themselves upwards seems to depend upon the screen width. Once it gets big enough, they look normal again.

Comment: I've removed `#Stretch`, and replaced `display: inline-block` with `float: left` on your div's, and gave them a margin. This will position your images next to each other, with spacing, and scale them down correctly on smaller screens.  http://jsfiddle.net/ATube/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You have a mismatch in your CSS classes (#CtDiv vs #CDiv).  This leaves CDiv as a block element.

If I may suggest though... the whole 'stretch' thing is unnecessary and the 24% just puts you into rounding errors.  I'd recommend something more like this:

HTML

```
<div id="tabBar">
   <div id="PDiv"></div>
   <div id="SDiv"></div>
   <div id="CDiv"></div>
   <div id="FDiv"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#tabBar {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #F3F3F3;
    width: 100%;
    height:40px;
}
#PDiv, #SDiv, #CDiv, #FDiv {
    background-color:#F3F3F3;
    background-size:contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:center center;
    width: 25%;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
    height:100%;
}
#PDiv {
    background-image:url(images/icons/tabBar/image0.png);
}
#SDiv {
    background-image:url(images/icons/tabBar/image1.png);
}
#CDiv {
    background-image:url(images/icons/tabBar/image2.png);
}
#FDiv {
    background-image:url(images/icons/tabBar/image3.png);
}
```

Generally, this should be somewhat lighter weight, but more importantly... allow you better separation of style and structure.

Even made you a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/F6khC/